# cannot download zip type file in FireFox in java

Tags: java, firefox, zip

I am unable to download zip file in Firefox browser it downloads as simple file type, on extracting able to retrieve the contents same if opened directly from browser pop up and when navigated to local folder in windows able to see in Zip.

below is my code

```
String mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".zip");

// creating byteArray stream, make it bufferable and passing this buffer
// to ZipOutputStream
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream;
try {
zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
} catch (IOException e1) {
throw new ItemNotFoundException("IO error downloading file");
}

int i = 1;
for (FileDTO file : fileList) {
// new zip entry and copying inputstream with file to
// zipOutputStream, after all closing streams
try {
zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(i + "_" + file.getFileName()));
IOUtils.copy(file.getFileObject().getObjectContent(), zipOutputStream);
zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
} catch (IOException e) {
throw new ItemNotFoundException("IO error downloading file");
}
i++;
}

if (zipOutputStream != null) {
try {
zipOutputStream.finish();
zipOutputStream.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
throw new ItemNotFoundException("IO error downloading file");
}

IOUtils.closeQuietly(zipOutputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Content-Type - application/zip